# Area 51 - reputation & downvote bug

Tags: support, area-51, voting

I have just came to Area 51 and my first action was to upvote some questions on a new proposal. The upvote went ok, I have spent all my votes, but then I have decided that I do not want to upvote one of the questions I have upvoted, and that I want to upvote instead, another question, because it is more relevant to me.

When I have tried to downvote, it said that I require 150 reputation to vote. So seems like the proposal upvoting has some special mechanism that can override the usual voting one, and that's not the case with downvoting.

Comment: For questions about Area 51, there is http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com; use "area51-meta" as tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting a downvote is different from un-casting an upvote. If you want to change your vote, you need to first "unvote", and then move the vote to another question. Click the upvote arrow beside the question you upvoted to un-upvote it.

Comment: Oh, a stupid question. I'd rather delete it, but I shall keep it since you have deserved the reputation )

Comment: @noncom It may make a good reference for the future, too. :)